# How can I import a module so that it is available for a calling PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of different powershell scripts that end users can import and use to configure their systems. The scripts are split up based on their functionality in a network share and may be updated to fix issues and add functionality.

How can I create a single script for my end users to import so that they have access to all the functions spread out through the collection of scripts?

Originally, I thought I could import all the modules into the global scope in a single script. Then an end user would just have to import that single script to have access to all the functions in the modules. Unfortunately, I get an error when importing the "import all" module.

**File Structure**

-/Base
 --/ScriptsType1
 -----/Script1
 -----/Script2
 --/ScriptsType2
 -----/Script3
 -----/Script4
--/ImportAllScripts.psm1

**Content of ImportAllScripts.psm1**

```
Import-Module .\ScriptsType1\Script1.psm1 -Global
Import-Module .\ScriptsType1\Script2.psm1 -Global
Import-Module .\ScriptsType2\Script3.psm1 -Global
Import-Module .\ScriptsType2\Script4.psm1 -Global
```

**User created script**

```
#Import all the scripts
Import-Module some_path\ImportAllVDIScripts.psm1

# Call a function from script 2
Run-ThatThing ("oh wow")
# Call a function from script 3
Run-ThatOtherTypeOfThing ("oh wow wow wow")
```

**Error**

> Import-Module : The specified module 'path\ImportAllVDIScripts.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found 
>   in any module directory.

Comment: You should probably investigate creating your own [local repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-local-psrepositories?view=powershell-6) instead of using a simple network share.

Comment: Yup, package your scripts as a proper module and publish it/them to a local repository